# Pass multi-select listbox values to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, formcollection

I have one ListBox which have many listitems with comma in-between e.g. abc, dce and cdf, dfe ..... and so on. Now if I select more than one listitem and try to collect it from controller FormCollection param, I am getting a list of comma-separated string e.g "abc, dce, cdf, dfe" but I need like this "abc, dce", "cdf, dfe", and so on.

One solution I have which is taking another parameter as `List<string> ListBoxId` which solves my issue.

Now, I just wanted to know is there any way to use the FormCollection itself and get the expected result.

Please advise.

Comment: Why would you use `FormCollection` instead of posting to a model?

Comment: @StephenMuecke The ListBox is bind with a non-model object..

Comment: Why? As always use a view model.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I just wanted to know is there any way to use the FormCollection
>   itself and get the expected result.

While I don't believe FormCollection is the proper way to handle this, here's what you can do:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourPostAction(FormCollection fc)
{
  var listvals = fc["stocks"];
  string[] splitVals = listvals.Split(new char[] { ',' });

  // do something with each value from the fc-list
  foreach (var str in splitVals)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Basically we took the FormCollection list and split it based on the "comma" delimiter.  From there, we get an array of strings which you can use however you like.

Comment: This will not work as I have listvals = "abc, dce, cdf, dfe" but I need like this "abc, dce", "cdf, dfe"..

Comment: per my example above, you have all the values contained in the string array.  You can certainly just combine array parts to get the strings you need.  Is there any pattern to the strings you need?